# Tooltip wordwrap issue

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tooltip is wordwrapping, the text spills to newline. How to fix this, I prefer to show texts in single line rather than multiline? Here is the
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zuzatu/edit?html,output)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
  <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor" data-placement="right"/>
                </div>    
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .tooltip{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

Comment: try this I modified your bin http://jsbin.com/vanorosari/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply css [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/white-space) which suppress line break within string.

```
.tooltip{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor" data-placement="right" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be different solutions for your problem. One possible solution is to change predefined tool tip style a little bit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.tooltip.fade.right.in {
  position: fixed;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor" data-placement="right" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```